# rms validate on models with a predict function such as coxph and glmnet

Tags: bootstrap, validation, cox-model, glmnet, rms

I would like to use bootstrapping to evaluate models generated by coxph and glmnet.
Would that be somehow possible with rms validate ?
From the documentation it seems limited to rms functions (cph, ols, etc.,)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For `coxph` use `cph`.  Otherwise as @purple51 answered, you will have to write your own `validate` methods.  The `rms` package `predab.resample` function, as used in the existing `validate` and `calibrate` functions, will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, limited to the models implemented in rms: cph, ols, etc. You can write your own bootstrap function or perhaps use the caret package although I'm sure it does the optimism bootstrap that validate() does.